# Regex or one liner code to manipulate string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to do the following:

**String before Code:**

```
"don\'t" 
"a\\b"
```

**String after Code:**

```
"\"don\\\'t\""    
"\"a\\\\b\""
```

I have written code which does this perfectly:

```
string x = "";
x += "\"";
foreach (var item in s)
{
    if (item == '\'' || item == '\"' || item == '\\')
    {
        x += '\\';
    }
    x += item;
}
x += "\"";
return x;
```

But is there a better way to do this? One liner code? I am not familiar with C# regex but I think this can be achieved with it. 
Thanks for any help...

Comment: This question is more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: so your input contains double quotes also?

Comment: Yes for example : "\"" will be changed into "\"\\\"\""

Comment: @OndrejJanacek How do I move this question to Codereview now/

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi As far as I know, you can't. Copy-paste it there and delete here.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek But I have seen questions that says on the top moved from xyz.stackexchange etc... Anyways I will if this gets closed here. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi I think that's moved by administrators. It's a pretty low chance it will get closed today, it's Sunday.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek ok, why don't you try answering the question? You any good with regex?

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi Nope. Why don't you try? There are many online regex builders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two better ways off the top of my head:

1. Use `StringBuilder`. This avoids multiple intermediate `string` allocations:

   ```
   var sb = new StringBuilder("\"");

   foreach (var item in s)
   {
       if (item == '\'' || item == '\"' || item == '\\')
           sb.Append('\\');

       sb.Append(item);
   }

   sb.Append('"');
   return sb.ToString();
   ```
2. As you said, use a regex replacement:

   ```
   return "\"" + Regex.Replace(s, @"[\\'""]", "\\$&") + "\"";
   ```

   The regex is `[\\'"]`, which means *match any of these chars: `\` or `'` or `"`*, and the replacement string is `\$&` which means: *replace this with a backslash followed by what you just matched*.

   The two string concatenations will be rewritten by the compiler to one `String.Concat` call.

Comment: @Syed "*this does not work*" doesn't tell me anything... *what* doesn't work?

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not check the edit. Well before it was returning the string with one less backslash... Its working perfectly now :) Thank you for your help.