# Regex or one liner code to format strings

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to do the following:

**String before code:**

```
"a"
"aa"
" a"
"a b c"
```

**String after code:**

```
"{a}"
"{aa}"          
"{a}"
"{a} {b} {c}"
```

I have written following code which does this just fine but I want to know is there a better way to do this ? One liner or `Regex` code? I am not good with C# `Regex`.

```
 string[] s = MyString.Split(' ');
 string x = "";
 foreach (var item in s)
 {
     if (item.Length > 0)
     {
         x += String.Format("{{{0}}}", item);
         if (s[s.Length-1] != item)
         {
             x += " ";
         }
     }
 }
 return x;
```

Comment: With your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009568/regex-or-one-liner-code-to-manipulate-string), you should ask it on [CodeReview.SE], not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the below regex and then replace the match with `{$1}`

```
@"\s*(\w+)\s*"
```

That is,

```
string result = Regex.Replace(inputstring, @"\s*(\w+)\s*", "{$1}");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uM3bR7/2)

Comment: I finally got it to work using `Regex.Replace(s, @"(\s*)(\w+)(\s*)\s*", "{$2}$3").TrimStart();` Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: I have another question can you please take a look at that for me?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77899/check-if-array-a-contains-all-elements-of-array-b-and-vice-verse-irrespective-of
I have asked this on codereview but got no attention, can you please give it a look?

Comment: sorry, i know regex only. I don't know about `C#`. I'm ready to solve regex related problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Join(" ", 
            MyString.Split(new char[]{' '},
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(s => "{" + s + "}"))
```

Comment: in the case of "a  " it return "{a}" but it should return "{a} ". :(

Comment: Can you explain the rule for that? Doesn't make much sense to me. Or is that just some special case?

Comment: The rules:
all words seperated by a space should be enclosed in curly brackets, starting space should be removed and ending space should be preserved.

Comment: What about multiple spaces in between?

Comment: They should be treated as one, for example "a   b" results in "{a} {b}". also "a   " will result int "{a} ".

Comment: Can't think of an elegant and efficient one-liner for that. The easiest way would be to something like `if(MyString.EndsWith(" ")) Append " " to result;` You might have better luck with Rawing's regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace

```
\s*(\w+)\b((?=.*\w)\s|)\s*
```

with `{$1}$2`.

[regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/uM3bR7/1)